# How do I put data from a controller into the navbar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a main controller with a navbar (that has the ui-view). Also, I have a controller that handles logging in. After logging in, it tries to get the user's info and puts it into $scope/$rootScope.

None of these variables are mantained in the navbar for me to put something like "Welcome, [nickname]!".

Comment: Please provide some code where you try to display `nickname`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a service that contains navbar data. Inject the service into both controllers. In the navbar controller, bind the service's data to the navbar view. After log in, call the service to add the data.

You'll probably want the user's data in other parts of the program, so it might make sense to name your service "userProfile".

```
angular.module('app').factory('userProfile', function() {
    return {};
});

angular.module('app').controller('NavBarCtrl', function(userProfile) {

    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.userProfile = userProfile;

});

<!-- NavBar.html -->
<span class="welcome">Welcome, {{$ctrl.userProfile.nickname}}</span>

angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', function(userProfile) {
    //Do Login stuff
    .then(function(profileData) {
        userProfile.nickname = profileData.nickname;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually makes sense. But is the service supposed to handle the ajax/$http calls or just to handle the data?

Comment: You could build it either way. I'd suggest the http requests should be separate and the `userProfile` should be dumb data.

Comment: Okay, but the HTTP requests on the login controller or on another service?

Comment: controllers shouldn't call http directly. Build a `loginService` to do that work. And the `loginService` can take care of populating `userProfile` too. Controller shouldn't do that either, really.